# Selenium element not interactable error on headless mode but works without headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape the webpage ted.europa.eu using Python with Selenium to retrieve information from the tenders. The script is supposed to be executed once a day with the new publications. The problem I have is that navigating to the new tenders I need Selenium to apply a filter to get only the ones from the same day the script it's executed. I already have the script for this and works perfectly, the problem is that when I activate the headless mode I get the following error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location`

This is the code I have that applies the filter I need:

```
import sys
import time
import re
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("../../../../.env")

sys.path.append("../src")
sys.path.append("../../../../utils")

from driver import *
from lted import LTED
from runnable import *

# start
print('start...')
counter = 0
start = datetime.now()

# get driver
driver = get_driver_from_url("https://ted.europa.eu/TED/browse/browseByMap.do%22)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

# change language to spanish
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lgId")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "lgId").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='lgId']/option[text()='español (es)']").click()

# click on "Busqueda avanzada"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "goToSearch")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "goToSearch").click()

# accept cookies and close tab
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cookie-consent-banner")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cookie-consent-banner']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cookie-consent-banner']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]").click()

# click on specific date and set to today
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "publicationDateSpecific")))
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "publicationDateSpecific")
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

driver.find_element(By.ID, "publicationDateSpecific").click()
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-state-highlight").click()

# click on search
driver.find_element(By.ID, "search").click()
```

From the imports the only think I need to explain is that from the line `from dirver import *` comes the method `get_driver_from_url()` that is used later in the code. This method looks like this:

```
def get_driver_from_url(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized") 
    options.add_argument("--headless") 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
```

As I said this code works perfectly without the headless mode, but when activated I get the error.

At first got another error and searching on the Internet found out that it could be because the element is not on screen, so I added the argument `"--start-maximized"` to make sure the Chrome tab is as big as possible and added the ActionChains to use `actions.move_to_element(element).perform()`, but I get this error on this exact code line.

Also tried changing the line `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "publicationDateSpecific")))` to `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "publicationDateSpecific")))` but it just didn't work.

Update: Also tried changing to `EC.visibility_of_element_located` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806577/python3-with-selenium-elementnotinteractable-object-has-no-size-and-location) post but didn't work either

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a long time of try and error, I found that adding

```
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "publicationDateSpecific")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,"+str(element.location["y"])+")")
```

makes the script work both in headless mode and normal mode

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the window size.
Try adding this:

```
   chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Comment: Hi! Already tried that too, but for what I saw on no headless mode this deppends directly on the screen the script is executed at. In my case I have a 2560 x 1440 monitor and running windows size with 1920 x 1080 opens a smaller tab than running the script without the option. Right now on no headless mode using only `--start-maximized` it already opens the new tab on max size, no need to specify the windows size. Does this change on headless mode?